# Grails 4 oracle connection stuck

Tags: oracle, jdbc, grails

When the application starts up it is validating the connection. This is the last log entry while it sits there waiting.

```
2020-07-29 15:01:20.743  INFO --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

It makes a connection in the DB and tries to run this.

```
SELECT 'NUMBER' AS type_name
     , 2   AS data_type
     , 38  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NUMBER' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'CHAR' AS type_name
     , 1   AS data_type
     , 2000 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'CHAR' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NCHAR' AS type_name
     , -15 AS data_type
     , 2000 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NCHAR' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'VARCHAR2' AS type_name
     , 12  AS data_type
     , 4000 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'VARCHAR2' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NVARCHAR2' AS type_name
     , -9  AS data_type
     , 4000 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'nVARCHAR2' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'DATE' AS type_name
     , 93  AS data_type
     , 7   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'DATE' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'DATE' AS type_name
     , 92  AS data_type
     , 7   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'DATE' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'TIMESTAMP' AS type_name
     , 93  AS data_type
     , 11  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'TIMESTAMP' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' AS type_name
     , -101 AS data_type
     , 13  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE' AS type_name
     , -102 AS data_type
     , 11  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'INTERVALYM' AS type_name
     , -103 AS data_type
     , 5   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'INTERVALYM' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'INTERVALDS' AS type_name
     , -104 AS data_type
     , 4   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'INTERVALDS' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'RAW' AS type_name
     , -3  AS data_type
     , 2000 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'RAW' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'LONG' AS type_name
     , -1  AS data_type
     , 2147483647 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'LONG' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'LONG RAW' AS type_name
     , -4  AS data_type
     , 2147483647 AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'LONG RAW' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NUMBER' AS type_name
     , -7  AS data_type
     , 1   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , '(1)' AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NUMBER' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NUMBER' AS type_name
     , -6  AS data_type
     , 3   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , '(3)' AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NUMBER' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NUMBER' AS type_name
     , 5   AS data_type
     , 5   AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , '(5)' AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NUMBER' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NUMBER' AS type_name
     , 4   AS data_type
     , 10  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , '(10)' AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NUMBER' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NUMBER' AS type_name
     , -5  AS data_type
     , 38  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NUMBER' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'FLOAT' AS type_name
     , 6   AS data_type
     , 63  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'FLOAT' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'REAL' AS type_name
     , 7   AS data_type
     , 63  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 3   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 1   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'REAL' AS local_type_name
     , -84 AS minimum_scale
     , 127 AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'BLOB' AS type_name
     , 2004 AS data_type
     , -1  AS precision
     , NULL AS literal_prefix
     , NULL AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 0   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'BLOB' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'CLOB' AS type_name
     , 2005 AS data_type
     , -1  AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'CLOB' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NCLOB' AS type_name
     , 2011 AS data_type
     , -1  AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'NCLOB' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'REF' AS type_name
     , 2006 AS data_type
     , 0   AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'REF' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ARRAY' AS type_name
     , 2003 AS data_type
     , 0   AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'ARRAY' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'STRUCT' AS type_name
     , 2002 AS data_type
     , 0   AS precision
     , '''' AS literal_prefix
     , '''' AS literal_suffix
     , NULL AS create_params
     , 1   AS nullable
     , 1   AS case_sensitive
     , 0   AS searchable
     , 0   AS unsigned_attribute
     , 0   AS fixed_prec_scale
     , 0   AS auto_increment
     , 'STRUCT' AS local_type_name
     , 0   AS minimum_scale
     , 0   AS maximum_scale
     , NULL AS sql_data_type
     , NULL AS sql_datetime_sub
     , 10  AS num_prec_radix
  FROM DUAL
ORDER BY data_type
```

I think it never finishes. Grails just hangs waiting. If I kill the oracle session then it continues on and the app loads. I am running DEBUG logging and the next log entry is this.

```
2020-07-29 15:01:37.142 DEBUG --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Environment details

- Grails 4.0.4
- Oracle DB version 12.1.0.2.0
- JDBC 4.1
- Oracle JDBC 12c drivers

application.yml

```
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: btpg
    gorm:
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false
    devtools:
        restart:
            additional-exclude:
                - '*.gsp'
                - '**/*.gsp'
                - '*.gson'
                - '**/*.gson'
                - 'logback.groovy'
                - '*.properties'
management:
    endpoints:
        enabled-by-default: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlet: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
management:
    endpoints:
        jmx:
            unique-names: true

---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false

dataSource:
    pooled: false
    jmxExport: false
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

    username: 'xxx'
    password: 'xxx'


environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none

            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.99.110:1521:SMPL
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: false
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1 from dual;
                validationQueryTimeout: 15
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post further connection settings or your persistence.xml?

Comment: Have you tried running the same SQL manually via e.g. SQLPlus? Looks like it should return more or less immediately, but best to verify the actual results.

Comment: The SQL runs just fine. Just not sure why grails does not finish and return control back to the application.

Comment: Just some shots in the dark: are you using liquibase for db migrations? it might be waiting for a lock to the changelog-table (e.g. locked from some previous attempt to start). also have you tried connecting to that DB from that exact host you try to run the application? could be some drop-ing firewall rules in place.

Comment: I am not running liquibase to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the datasource dialect in your yaml file. The bolded line is what you are missing.

```
dataSource:
    pooled: false
    jmxExport: false
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    ################ Add this line ###############
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect 
    username: 'xxx'
    password: 'xxx'
```